# Dependency-Check Offline Issue (mvn -o)

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-check-plugin, owasp-dependency-check

I am currently facing a challenge with running the Dependency-Check plugin in offline mode using "mvn -o."

Although I have mirrored all external resources locally, I encounter an issue that prevents successful execution. The specific error message I'm encountering is:

"(default-cli) on project parent: Goal requires online mode for execution but Maven is currently offline."

Given the specific context of my project, offline operations are a requirement due to security considerations. I would greatly appreciate any insights, workarounds, or suggestions from the community on how to make Dependency-Check compatible with the "mvn -o" flag and resolve this offline issue.

Thank you in advance for your expertise and assistance.

Comment: It's a kind of circular issue.. because to get up-to-date information you have to access external information sources... if being off-line you can get them..

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/), this plugin

```
downloads and processes the data from the 
National Vulnerability Database (NVD) hosted by NIST: 
https://nvd.nist.gov
```

In order to reach https://nvd.nist.gov, it must have an internet connection. The plugin needs the source data in order to do the desired checking.